# IE 7 float issue not ignoring content

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I am getting an issue within IE7. I have the created the following html to demonstrate the possible 'issue'.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="head">
    </div>
    <div id="left">
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    </div>
    <div id="no-float">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#555555;
}
#head {
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:black;
    float:left;
}
#left {
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
}
#right {
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
}

#no-float {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:green;
}
```

Now I expect the green no-float div to be at the very top left of the container as from my understanding the normal content should completely ignore the floated content. This works as expected in all browsers I have tested by not in IE7. Is it a problem with my understanding of floats or is this a bug in IE7? If it is a bug can anyone point me in the right direction to fix it? Here is a jsfiddle of the problem.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vQhAN/)

Comment: IE is pure evil. http://jsfiddle.net/vQhAN/1/ this works, but I know it's not an answer

Comment: Can't believe that worked as it makes no sense to me!

Comment: yeah but not working in firefox ;] just saying IE+relative = pure evil

Comment: Yeah. won't work in chrome either so not the fix, just strange!

Comment: Try absolute positioning on the green and relative on container. I don't have IE7 to test on. http://jsfiddle.net/vQhAN/6/

Comment: @fredsbend Just gave that a try and the green moves outside the container in IE7 but not in other browsers.

Comment: Try absolute positioning on the container too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The float model of IE7 is horrid. [See here](http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEWflm.html) for issues related to your problem, and why it won't be fixed through using just floats. You are going to have to resort to absolute positioning if you want to keep your elements in the source order you have. This could be conditionally fed to IE7, or it would work as is for all modern browsers.

### [Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/vQhAN/14/)

Add `position: relative` to the `#container`, then

```
#no-float {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:green;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: @fredsbend: That's because in your fiddle you did not set the `top` or `left` properties. I've tested mine in IE7 and it does work.

Comment: Oh. Good coding then. I guess we should note then that in IE 7 top and left have no default value.

Comment: +1 for the link regarding float issues. Ah that's where I was going wrong. I attempted this but without specifying the top and left. Thanks for your help this will solve my problem!